# Ajax to send json object to server and recieve json object sent by server back in ajax(Calling page)

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have index.php page in which I have an html form, on submit I want to AJAX call my.php php page(so that page should not be reloaded) I am using post in ajax to send POST data to my.php page. On my.php page I want to send a JSON object to some server, in return that server will send me another JSON object.  Now I want this recieved JSON object on my page index.php(in ajax and then on index php) I want to parse that json object to get individual values.

Here is my code, Please I am first time doing AJAX please do help writing my code.

```
$("#ok").on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({ 
        url: '/final/my.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        type: 'post',
         data: $(this).serialize(),
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
        // I don't have what to add here to recieve that $arr JSON object from my.php page  

        },

        error: function(data) {
        alert('An error occurred');
        }
});
});
```

MY.PHP page contents

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


    $size = $_POST['size'];
    $budget = $_POST['budget']; 
    $mob_no = $_POST['phone_no'];
    $json = array('mobile_no'=>$mob_no,'size'=>$size,'budget'=>$budget);
    $myCurl = "curl -i **.**.**.***:****/1/user/web -d '". json_encode($json)."' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'";
    //echo $myCurl;
    $reply = shell_exec($myCurl);
    $arr=var_dump(json_decode($reply, true));
     echo($arr); // ****This JSON object I want to get on Index.php page and extract values

    //foreach ($arr as &$value){
    //${"mob_no".$value}= $arr[0][mobile_no];
    //${"size".$value}= $arr[1][size];



    }

    ?>
```

Comment: as I can see in you `php` code, you have `mobile_no` and `size` in your `array`. so you can access it in your `jquery` in the `success` part like this: `data[0].mobile_no`. and you can use a `for` to loop trough all the returned records. please take a look at the **Examples** section in [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: @ EhsanT, thanks for your time,Actually that $json array data I dont want, I want that $arr or $reply data(which is new data sent by some server to me)  can you please write exactly what I need to write in success part?

Comment: I know that and the `data` which is passed to the `callback function for success` is the returned value from `MY.PHP` file and not the `data parameter` in your `ajax` call. and since I do not know what are the elements in the `json` data and what you want to do with them in the `success` part, I do not know what to write for you. again, please take a look at the example section of the link I provided before and write your code and update your post here if you had any more questions.